# How to apply if satement and calculate in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, contact-form-7, calculated-field

How can I apply the if statement and calculate a set of radio buttons using JavaScript?

It works as of now with adding up the total. but I would like it to apply the $150.00 off only when they select yes.

Here is the radio buttons that I am trying to work with.

```
    <p>Baby Plan<br />
        [radio BPSUBPT id:BPSUBPT class:radio-vertical "Baby Plan $300.00 3 Sessions" "Baby Plan $500.00 4 Sessions"] </p>

    <p>Did you have a Newborn session With ADP? <br />
[radio BPSUPQ id:BPSUPQ class:radio-vertical "Yes $-150 off" "No $000.00"]</p>

    <p>Baby Plan Totals: <br />
    Baby Plan Price: [text BPSUTotal 28/28 id:BPSUTotal]
    Discount Amount: [text BPSUDA 8/8 id:BPSUDA]

    Total Price: <span id="total"></span>
```

My JavaScript as I have now:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var inputs = $('input[name="BPSUBPT"], input[name="BPSUPQ"]');
    $(inputs).click(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $(inputs).filter(':checked').each(function() {
            // Now including the - sign
            var value = ($(this).val()).match(/\$(-?[0-9]*)/)[1];
            if (value) {
                // I'm now ADDing the total
                // total = total + parseInt(value);
                total += parseInt(value);
            }
        });
        $('#total').html('$' + total);
          $('#BPSUBA').val('$' + total);
});
    $('input[name="BPSUBPT"]').click(function() {
        $(this).blur();
        $('#BPSUBPP').val($(this).val());
    })
    $('input[name="BPSUPQ"]').click(function() {
        $(this).blur();
        $('#BPSUDA').val($(this).val());
   });
}); 
</script>
```

I would like to have the radio button that has the value of Yes| $150.00 off to be subtracted from the set of radio buttons from baby plan.

Comment: Giri that did not work, the only set that has a pipe is the Did you have a Newborn session With ADP? radio set. I am going to head for bed it is getting late here. I will be on in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out your old code and try this instead. Also sometimes when you have two fields with the same name, it could get tricky and sometimes even fail.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var radio1 = $('input[name="BPSUBPT"]');
    var radio2 = $('input[name="BPSUBQ"]');
    var selectedValue = '';
    $(radio1).on('click', function(){
        $(radio1).each(function(index, value){
            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
            if(checked && index == '0'){
                selectedValue = 300;
                $('#BPSUTotal').val(selectedValue);
            } else if(checked && index == '1'){
                selectedValue = 500;
                $('#BPSUTotal').val(selectedValue);
            }
        });
    });

    $(radio2).on('click', function(){
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        if(checked && selectedValue != ''){
            var oldValue = $('#BPSUTotal').val();
            var newValue = oldValue - 150;
            $('#BPSUTotal').val(newValue);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Giri thank you for answering my question, I am using contact form 7 for my forms. how would I apply this to my form, I am new to this

Comment: Did you try adding this to your $document.ready function? Probably need an event handler. I'll update the answer with the event handler if that helps

Comment: yes I did and it did not do anything, let me give you the link to the form maybe this will help you a bit to see what I trying to do [Page](http://www.annadecarlophotography.com/baby-plan-sign-up/)    I also trying to get a copy of the 150 value to a text field,

Comment: Yep i can see whats happening there. We will need to tweak the code a bit. I'll reedit the answer here once im done.

Comment: The issue here is input type radio has a value = "baby plans $300 sessions" as string. Reason why .val() and calculation doesn't run.

Comment: now I have a Qestion if I take that pipe out and just put yes would there be a way to apply a hidden value some where with out the client seeing it then subtract it but showing the amount in a text box named discount amount of the hidden value

Comment: But the rendered output doesn;t have the pipe anywhere. the value="Baby....." string.

Comment: I added a comment on the top

Comment: if it cant be done I am happy with what I have. but now I having a problem with another form I cant figure out. would you mind helping me out on it  [new question I need help on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959891/calculate-checkbox-with-multple-selcet)