# How to subtract values of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, subtraction, calculated-field

How can I calculate a set of radio buttons using JavaScript?
It works as of now with adding up the total. but I would like it to Subtract the $150.00 off.

this is what I been working on now I get $Nan

```
<p>Baby Plan<br />
    [radio BPSUBPT id:BPSUBPT class:radio-vertical "Baby Plan $300.00 3 Sessions" "Baby Plan $500.00 4 Sessions"] </p>

<p>Did you have a Newborn session With ADP? <br />
[radio BPSUPQ id:BPSUPQ class:radio-vertical "Yes$ -150 off" "No"]


<p>Baby Plan Totals: <br />
Baby Plan Price: [text BPSUBPP 28/28 id:BPSUBPP]
Discount Amount: [text BPSUDA 8/8 id:BPSUDA]

Total Price: <span id="total"></span



<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
      var inputs = $('input[name="BPSUBPT"], input[name="BPSUPQ"]');
            $(inputs).click(function() {
                var total = 0;
                $(inputs).filter(':checked').each(function() {
                    var value = ($(this).val()).match(/\$([0-9]*)/)[1];
                    total = (parseInt(total) - parseInt(value)) 
                })
               $('#total').html('$' + total);
            });
            $('input[name="BPSUBPT"]').click(function() {
                $(this).blur();
                $('#BPSUBPP').val($(this).val());
            })
            $('input[name="BPSUPQ"]').click(function() {
                $(this).blur();
                $('#BPSUDA').val($(this).val());
       });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Use subtraction operator for this: `-`

Comment: I have tried and it still add the total but with a - sign I even tied adding this total = parseInt(total) - parseInt(value); And it will not work

Comment: Say please, what thing you use for your layouts?

Comment: I am using contact form 7 here is my [page](http://www.annadecarlophotography.com/baby-plan-sign-up/) to see what I am talking about

Comment: read your browser console, you use null-result of `match` as array

Comment: I don't under stand I am new to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably just ADD the totals:

```
<p>Baby Plan<br />
[radio BPSUBPT id:BPSUBPT class:radio-vertical "Baby Plan $300.00 3 Sessions" "Baby Plan $500.00 4 Sessions"] </p>

<p>Did you have a Newborn session With ADP? <br />
[radio BPSUPQ id:BPSUPQ class:radio-vertical "Yes $-150 off" "No"]
<!-- beware here because I changed "Yes$ -150" to "$-150" -->

<p>Baby Plan Totals: <br />
Baby Plan Price: [text BPSUBPP 28/28 id:BPSUBPP]
Discount Amount: [text BPSUDA 8/8 id:BPSUDA]

Total Price: <span id="total"></span
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var inputs = $('input[name="BPSUBPT"], input[name="BPSUPQ"]');
    $(inputs).click(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $(inputs).filter(':checked').each(function() {
            // Now including the - sign
            var value = ($(this).val()).match(/\$(-?[0-9]*)/)[1];
            if (value) {
                // I'm now ADDing the total
                // total = total + parseInt(value);
                total += parseInt(value);
            }
        });
        $('#total').html('$' + total);
    });
    $('input[name="BPSUBPT"]').click(function() {
        $(this).blur();
        $('#BPSUBPP').val($(this).val());
    });
    $('input[name="BPSUPQ"]').click(function() {
        $(this).blur();
        $('#BPSUDA').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think whats happening is you're working with negative numbers.

When you do `total = total - parseInt(value);` you are subtracting the value as determined by the radio buttons from 0. (`var total = 0;`).
So your total is actually a negative number.

You probably want to add there, and then make the value of the 150 discount `-150`, and add that to your total.

Comment: so just change 150 to -150

Comment: That's the second part. the main thing is this: `total = total - parseInt(value);` which is subtracting the value of the package from the total (which is 0). change that to `total = total + parseInt(value);` then change the 150 to -150 and see what happens.

Comment: Ok now I am getting NAN for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Don't use decrement/incrementation of total, count right total every time.

Add attribute `cost` to each valuable input(price or discount) and:
Try this:

```js
$('input').click(function(){
   var total = 0;
   $('input').filter(':checked').each(function(){
      var cost = $(this).attr('cost');
      cost = cost ? parseFloat(cost) : 0;
      console.log(cost);
      total += cost;
   });
   $('#total').text('$'+Math.max(total, 0));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input cost="300" type="radio" name="BPSUBPT" value="Baby Plan $300.00 3 Sessions"> Baby Plan $300.00 3 Sessions<br/>
<input cost="500" type="radio" name="BPSUBPT" value="Baby Plan $500.00 3 Sessions"> Baby Plan $500.00 3 Sessions<br/>

<input cost="-150" type="radio" name="BPSUPQ" value="Yes $150.00 off" />
Apply Discount?<br/>
<input cost="0" type="radio" name="BPSUPQ" value="No" />No<br/>

<div id="total">
```

Update:

Comment: `inputs is not defined`. Why you didnt declare them?

Comment: and no attributes with price... You should add something, because `$-150 off` is ugly..

Comment: you can simple add a class `discount` and check(`hasClass('discount')`) and `*-1` before sum

Comment: Like this  [radio BPSUPQ id:BPSUPQ class:Discount "Yes *-1" "No"]

Comment: I cant have it that way I will never get a copy of their input

Comment: what if I use a pipe like this  [radio BPSUPQ id:BPSUPQ class:radio-vertical "Yes|$150.00 off" "No"]

Comment: Try `[radio BPSUPQ id:BPSUPQ class:radio-vertical cost:"-150" "Yes $150.00 off" "No"]`. I can't to learn some wordpress plugin now, sorry..

Comment: I really do not want to apply discount button, I want it so they click yes a discount is applied  I do not want clients apply a discount if they have not had a session by be before

Comment: I even have tired it this way and it will not work [question1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941899/how-to-apply-if-satement-and-calculate-in-javascript)

Comment: You should understand what are you doing for get started. Good Luck.